# as.POSIXct/as.POSIXlt doesn't like .61 milliseconds

Tags: r, datetime-format

Here's a weird artifact.  I'm converting tens of thousands of character vectors into a datetime class, like so:

```
alles$DateTime=as.POSIXct(alles$roughdate, tz="EST",format="%Y%m%d.%H%M%S.%OS")
```

Pretty straight forward. The character string (`alles$roughdate`) is in the format `YYYYMMDD.HHMMSS.ss` with the `.ss` being milliseconds.  The above code works, as would be expected. However, if the milliseconds equal .61, it returns an NA instead of a date time value.

This isn't too bad, but when dealing with tens of thousands cells, a few hundred are always returned as NA.  Milliseconds always .61, doesn't matter what the rest of the date is.  I do *need* those dates.

I've tried isolating those files and then merging the two data frames together again, but that doesn't seem to work.  All of my dates are suddenly NA.

Any thoughts?

Example

```
vec <- c("20150101.010101.60", "20150101.010101.61", "20150101.010101.62") 
as.POSIXlt(vec, tz="EST", format="%Y%m%d.%H%M%S.%OS")
#[1] "2015-01-01 01:01:60 EST" NA "2015-01-01 01:01:01 EST"
```

Comment: it looks like your format string is just wrong (as pointed out in @nrussell's answer), but just out of intellectual curiosity I'd love to know what's actually going on to trigger this particular undefined behaviour.  I'm too lazy to trace through the underlying C code, though ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change the format for the time part to be `%H%M%OS` instead of `%H%M%S.%OS`, it seems to parse correctly. You may have to adjust your `options` so see this:

```
as.POSIXlt(vec, tz = "EST", format = "%Y%m%d.%H%M%OS")
#[1] "2015-01-01 01:01:01 EST" "2015-01-01 01:01:01 EST" 
#[3] "2015-01-01 01:01:01 EST"

options(digits.secs = 2)
as.POSIXlt(vec, tz = "EST", format = "%Y%m%d.%H%M%OS")
# [1] "2015-01-01 01:01:01.60 EST" "2015-01-01 01:01:01.61 EST"
# [3] "2015-01-01 01:01:01.62 EST"
```

Comment: I've been subsetting those resulting in "NA", converting those character strings into timestamps with %H%M%S, and then manually adding 0.61.  I didn't even think to adjust the options.  I'll test that out, thanks!!

Comment: Update:

I got distracted by other aspects of this project, but the option (digits.secs = 2) suggested did not solve this problem.  61 milliseconds still stick out.  Strangely, it can be 610 millisecond, and from what I can tell, the code runs properly.  Weird glitch in the code. Thanks everyone!  I've got my long round-about way of adding them in post, and that works for now.